# How can get values using LINQ from multilevel variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to unable to fetch values using LINQ. I am using below code for fetching data.

```
  SearchParameters sp3 = new SearchParameters()
        {
            Filter = "name eq 'test'",
            Top = 5,
            QueryType = QueryType.Full,
            Select= new List<string>() { "Query" },
        };

         if (highlights)
        {
            sp3.HighlightPreTag = "<b>";
            sp3.HighlightPostTag = "</b>";
        }
        DocumentSearchResult suggestResult = _indexClient1.Documents.Search(term,sp3);

            List<string> suggestions = (from p in suggestResult
                                   .Results.Select(s => s.Document)
                                   .Select(y => y.Values.ToString())
                                    select p).ToList();
```

Hierarchy is Document->Result->Query.

I am getting values till Result level but I want to get data till Query Level. 
I am not expert in LINQ.

screenshot

[image]

output

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs specified in code. Be sure to be **explicit** about the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
suggestResult.Results.SelectMany(s => s.Document.Select(d => d.Query)).ToList()
```

It should give you a list of all Query-Objects over all Document Results.

If you want the Query as string you have to get another property of Query in the inner Select or call ToString() on it.